# Hide reviews from google search

Tags: google-search

Some times i am looking for a game to play and the google search result give me the reviews, but I would like to play  without being biased by the reviews.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well..that's not possible. Google search engine displays reviews automatically and there is no way "disabling" or "hiding" them. You can remove bad reviews by reporting them, but there is no possibility of hiding them altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide that with Google. But you can use another search engine. On Duckduckgo for example when you search for "Battle princess madelyn", there is no score of this sort beeing displayed.